# ConcurrentModificationException in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I was trying to fetch data from database and keep a count of it. If the count is 1 then update should happen else if its zero then insert. Before that when I get the dbData.count(), I get ConcurrentModificationException. The metric_id is an illiterated values received from finaloutput dataset.

`DataSet<Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, String>> method1=finaloutput.map(new Writents(fhir_resource));
method1.printToErr();`

the logical part of Writents class is as follows:

`String sourcequery="SELECT id,topic,from,to,metric_id from  metrics where (topic='"+nt+"') AND (metric_id=('"+metric_id+"')) and (date(from)=(('"+StartDate+"')::date)) and (date(to) = (('"+EndDate+"')::date))";`

```
    dbData =env.createInput(JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
                                           .setDrivername(Utils.properties_fetch("drivername"))
                                           .setDBUrl(Utils.properties_fetch("dbURL"))`
                                           .setUsername(Utils.properties_fetch("username"))
                                           .setPassword(Utils.properties_fetch("password"))
                                           .setQuery(sourcequery)                                                                           
                                           .setRowTypeInfo(new RowTypeInfo(BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,BasicTypeInfo.DATE_TYPE_INFO,BasicTypeInfo.DATE_TYPE_INFO,BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO))
                                           .finish());  
    return new Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, String>(nt,metric_id.toString(),StartDate.toString(),EndDate.toString(),ExecutionDate.toString(),topic,(existance=(dbData.count()==0)?"NO DATA THERE":"DATA THERE"));
```

When I do debugging i get no error, but when i run the program i get the ConcurrentModificationException and the job fails.

The exception I am getting is as follows:

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.OperatorTranslation.translateToPlan(OperatorTranslation.java:51)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.createProgramPlan(ExecutionEnvironment.java:954)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.createProgramPlan(ExecutionEnvironment.java:921)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment.execute(LocalEnvironment.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:815)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.count(DataSet.java:398)
    at com.cm.analytics.nts.Writents.map(Writents.java:177)
    at com.cm.analytics.nts.Writents.map(Writents.java:1)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.MapDriver.run(MapDriver.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:490)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:355)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Comment: Debugging would be easy if you add full stack trace here and also the snippet of affected code according to your stack trace.

Comment: The snippet of the affected code is the above one itself.

Comment: Yes, but we still need the stack trace. Without that, it is impossible tell what caused the exception.

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope this is what i missed before.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the cause of this issue?

Comment: No I wasnt able to find out.